# Передача настроек приложения через командую строку

Tags: java, spring, rest

Каким образом можно передать и обработать properties через командую строку `main`? Какие при этом аннотации Spring требуется использовать?
У меня имеется конфигурационный файл с аннотациями `@Configuration`, `@ConfigurationPropeties`. На поля класса наложены аннотации на соответствующие поля в передаваемом файле. Как теперь имя файла передать из класса  `@SpringBootApplication` в класс `@Configration`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передать имя файла как сиситемное свойство.

```
@PropertySource("file:${myPropertyName}")
```

при запуске добавить `-DmyPropertyName=/home/user1/my.properties`.

Comment: а как в Spring добавить данную строку при запуске?

Comment: А как вы запускаете?

Comment: Тесты запускаю с использованием Mockito. А вообще имеется класс с аннотацией SpringBootApplication,а в нем уже метод main.

Comment: Это понятно, но как вы запускаете приложение? Через командную строку? В IDE?

Comment: Запускаю в IDE/

Comment: там при запуске должны быть  VM options. Вот туда и прописать.